# Can someone explain me this typescript method signature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I have started off with the following lambda function in typescript:

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  
}
```

After learning about typescript I know that the arguments in the function are given types(APIGatewayProxyEvent and Context respectively). Similarly the function's return type is defined by adding it at the end after a colon `(Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>)`.

There's still a type being used here: `handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler`

What does this type signify? What is it known as? It's definitely not the return type of the method then what is it?

I have scoured through various typescript blogs and still couldn't find any information about this.

Thanks!

Comment: That's your expected variable type. E.g. `const x: () => boolean = (): boolean => false;`, so now `x` is of the type function which has to return a boolean. Another example, this would then fail: `const x: () => boolean = () => "hello world"`. Basically it's the type of the function, you've assigned to `handler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can also have types, for example:

```
type MyFunc = (a: number) => string;
```

Then when you create a function, you can assign it that type:

```
const actualFunction: MyFunc = (a: number): string {
  return 'hi';
}
```

Giving the constant a type enforces that your argument and return types match the signature of the type, and if you accidentally messed up the return type, having `APIGatewayProxyHandler` there will cause typescript to complain.